# Why have “unidirectional ‘mapping’” tables?

Tags: mysql, database-design, sharding

I've been reading about how Pinterest sharded their MySQL databases [here](https://medium.com/@Pinterest_Engineering/sharding-pinterest-how-we-scaled-our-mysql-fleet-3f341e96ca6f).

One of the things they talk about in that post is having “unidirectional ‘mapping’” tables such as

```
 CREATE TABLE board_has_pins (
  board_id INT,
  pin_id INT,
  sequence INT,
  INDEX(board_id, pin_id, sequence)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

and then an opposite `pin_owned_by_board`.

My question is, why would you have these “unidirectional tables” for “mapping” and not just one with a different index structure? I don't think it can stop duplicates due to the sequence being a unix timestamp, but the index does limit only being able to select by the `board_id` in this instance or the full index (efficiently anyway). So why not have separate indices on `board_id` and `pin_id`? Is this down to the fact that a pin could in theory live on a separate shard even though they try to keep them on the same one so it makes sense to make it “unidirectional”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that it is a strange table.

No uniqueness constraint, so dups can occur.  I would change `INDEX` to `PRIMARY KEY`.

No index the opposite direction, so unlikely to use it that way.  I would add another column and `INDEX(bin_id, board_id, pin_to_board sequence)`

On the other hand, perhaps there is a lot of activity in the table -- such as updating all the sequence values frequently.  Still, InnoDB would really prefer to have a `PRIMARY KEY`, and that triple seems like the 'right' PK.

I would probably work harder to avoid potential timestamp dups.